# Generate firebase auth token to unit test golang admin sdk

Tags: firebase, go, firebase-authentication

I am building a golang rest service with the firebase admin sdk . I take the authentication token from the client and validate it in the back-end with the function `VerifyIDToken` from the firebase auth package . Then I take the UID and insert some documents .

I am trying to generate unit tests of the token validation but I don´t know any way to generate this tokens directly from go .

There is a function to create authentication tokens ? Or I should create a function to send my credentials to the emulator and get the authentication token ?

Comment: could you use their testing function as a base? https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-go/blob/master/auth/auth_test.go